# Does someone who didn't vote have a right to complain?

Tags: united-states, bill-of-rights

So this always comes up when I'm talking to people I know. I complain about this politician getting elected but because I missed voting because the voting precinct wasn't there on the day of the elections, thus I failed to vote. Their response is "you have no right to complain because you didn't vote".

**Do people that didn't vote have a right to complain about who got elected and the way they run things?**

Comment: What, like a legal right? Yes, complaint about government action is very well protected speech. Or are you asking something else?

Comment: Not a legal right, more like on moral grounds. The people I know I have no right to complain about the current administration since I wasn't able to vote, and hence I did not do anything to affect the turnout of the election, so I should just shut up and live with the consequence. That's what they're saying.

Comment: right, so that question is well outside the scope of this stackexchange.

Comment: You could turn the question around. Does someone who voted have a right to complain? After all they took part in the election so they should accept the result.

Comment: In the US and most of the free world, you have the right to freedom of speech.  That means that yes you can complain and it is your right to do so.  In some ways its a bit hypocritical to complain, but that is off topic here.

Comment: Do we have morality/ethics SE? Perhaps Philisophy.SE would be more on-topic

Comment: [Relevant Dilbert from 1993](http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/1993-04-17/)

Comment: @Chad The problem with freedom of speech is that it works both way. DidNotVote has the right to complain and his peers have the right to complain about him complaining.

Comment: @Philipp - And people have a right to complain about them complaining even if they are the people doing the complaining... this loop can recurse infinitely.

Comment: The people responsible for posting infinitely recursive comments have been purged.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your right to complain about the [government is a fundamental right](http://www.givemeliberty.org/constitutionlobby/InterpretationOfRTP.htm), protected by the bill of rights. The [first amendment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution) states:

> Congress shall make no law respecting an establishment of religion, or prohibiting the free exercise thereof; or abridging the freedom of speech, or of the press; or the right of the people peaceably to assemble, and **to petition the Government for a redress of grievances.**